# DynamoDB - scan and filter map with nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm using nodejs to  scan and filter a collection in dynamodb that looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "teste123",
    "id": "4bbe0f00-67c3-11e7-a6be-b9c9fc540ac2",
    "clustermembers": [
        {
            "email": "teste@teste.com",
            "role": "ADMIN",
            "id": "4bbe0f00-67c3-11e7-a6be-b9c9fc540ac2"
        }
    ]
}
```

With the following pice of code:

```
var params = {
    TableName : "mytable",
    FilterExpression : "clustermembers.email = :p_email",
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
        ":p_email": {"S": req.params.usr_email}  
    } 
};

var promiseQuery = client.scan(params).promise();

promiseQuery
    .then(function(data) {
        res.send({clusters: data.Items});
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('ERROR -  get all clusters by user = ' + err);
        res.status(500).send('ERROR -  get all clusters by user = ' + err);
    });
```

It should return one record but I'm getting no results. What I'm missing here?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array index has to be included to get the value from List data type. Otherwise, you may need to use **CONTAINS** function. However, the CONTAINS function requires all the attributes in the object to map the item. In your scenario, you need to know email, id and role to use **CONTAINS** function.

**Note:-**

The below solution wouldn't work if you have multiple cluster members and you would like to match members present in the other occurrences in the array. In order to achieve that you need to use **CONTAINS** function by providing all three attributes in the object.

```
var params = {
    TableName: "mytable",
    FilterExpression: "clustermembers[0].email = :emailVal",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":emailVal": 'teste@teste.com'
    }
};
```

Comment: Hello notionquest. First of all, thanks for the help. This approach does work but I don't have all the info in this scenario. I'm checking if the user logged in has access to that "cluster" and I'll have multiple "cluster members". I think it's better to move this data to another since there's no way to seek for a specific email in the sub-collection, right? Again, thanks for the help.